# Calling Ajax method using javascript function

Tags: javascript, ajax, html

I'm working with jQuery Mobile.

My Code for move to **`details` div** ::

```
<a href="#details" data-ajax="true" data-transition="pop" data-role="button" data-inline="false" data-icon="info">Go To Details</a>
```

Now, I want to authenticate user with Facebook.

So I have applied ::

```
<a href="javascript:userLogin()" data-ajax="true" data-transition="pop" data-role="button" data-inline="false" data-icon="info"> Login with Faceook </a>
```

Function Calling for Authentication

```
function userLogin() {
     FB.login(
          function(response) {
               if (response.authResponse) {
                   alert('logged in');

                   FB.api('/me', function(response) {
                     alert("Welcome " + response.name);
                   });
                } else {
                   alert('not logged in');
                }
           },
           { scope: "email" }
     );
}
```

I'm getting valid user response after authentication.
Now I want to navigate to that **`details` div**.

So, how can I implement that ajax code after successfully login ??

Any suggestion will be appreciated.

Thanks.

Comment: You can set it as cookies and then redirect to detail page.

Comment: if you have jquery try `$('a[href="#details"]').click()`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Instead of changing the `href` attribute directly, you should bind the `onclick` event to a function returning `true`.

Modify your `a` tag.

```html
<a href="#details" onclick="javascript:return userLogin()" data-ajax="true" data-transition="pop" data-role="button" data-inline="false" data-icon="info">Go To Details</a>
```

Modify your `userLogin` function:

```js
function userLogin() {
    FB.login(
        function(response) {
            if (response.authResponse) {
                alert('logged in');

                FB.api('/me', function(response) {
                    alert("Welcome " + response.name);
                });
            } else {
                alert('not logged in');
            }
        },
        { scope: "email" }
    );
    return true;
}
```

It seems that `FB.login` is an asynchronized operation. If you want to redirect after the login action, try to modify the `location.hash` after login. Note that the return value has changed to `false`.

```js
function userLogin() {
    var hash = '#details';
    FB.login(
        function(response) {
            if (response.authResponse) {
                alert('logged in');
                FB.api('/me', function(response) {
                    alert("Welcome " + response.name);
                    window.location.hash = hash;
                });
            } else {
                alert('not logged in');
            }
        },
        { scope: "email" }
    );
    return false;
}
```

Comment: Not working.. It directly go to that div without authenticate user.

Comment: Thanks mate. Solved..:) But I've edited in <a> tag and remove href attribute because it navigates before authenticated. Again Thanks..:)

Answer (score 0):

Use $.ajax() for making a call to the Facebook API to authenticate and in the callback function of the ajax function, call the click event of the details link.

Maybe something like this,

```
  $.ajax({
     url : 'https://graph.facebook.com/me'+whatever,
     success : function(){
        $('#details').click()
     }
  });
```

The success function will be called when the ajax call is successful.